# Remove user with CSOM C# gives System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: development, csom, provider-hosted-app

With the following code I'm trying to remove an external user programmatically from a Provider Hosted App:

```
Context.Web.SiteUsers.RemoveById(userId);
Context.ExecuteQuery();
```

This is giving me a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` so I opened the AppManifest.xml file and checked the **Allow the app to make app-only calls to SharePoint**. I also gave fullcontrol to the following:

- User profile(social)
- List
- Tenant
- Web
- Site Collection

but still getting the error.

Anything else I need to do? The user account under which it runs has enough privileges to add and remove users from within the SharePoint dashboards but I need to do it programmatically as other users will need the ability to add and remove users but won't get those user privileges themselves.

Comment: Are you able to perform simple operations on Web from your app, say create a list item? Please put the code by which context is created and also how you get the userId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying with a standard connection string with username / password combination. That worked out nicely for retrieving information but apparently not for removing a user. I changed the authentication and pass in the HttpContext and now it works out.